# filter array of objects with conditionals

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract those objects with the value required = true. I can make a forEach and push into a new array, but I would like to know how to do this with another method.

```js
const arr = [
    { customFields: [{ id: 0, required: true }, { id: 1, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 2, required: false }, { id: 3, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 4, required: false }, { id: 5, required: true }] },
]

const requireds = arr.map(x => x.customFields.filter(y => y.required ))
console.log(requireds)

// expected = [{ id: 0, required: true }, { id: 5, required: true } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten it first so you have a plain array of objects before filtering.

```js
const arr = [
    { customFields: [{ id: 0, required: true }, { id: 1, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 2, required: false }, { id: 3, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 4, required: false }, { id: 5, required: true }] },
]

const requireds = arr
  .flatMap(obj => obj.customFields)
  .filter(y => y.required);
console.log(requireds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simyly use a `.flatMap()` to collect the results of your `.filter()` operation:

```js
const arr = [
    { customFields: [{ id: 0, required: true }, { id: 1, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 2, required: false }, { id: 3, required: false }] },
    { customFields: [{ id: 4, required: false }, { id: 5, required: true }] },
]

const requireds = arr.flatMap(x => x.customFields.filter(y => y.required ))
console.log(requireds)

// expected = [{ id: 0, required: true }, { id: 5, required: true } ]
```